# IIB Flow with HTTP Input Node at beginning returns "Unsupported Method: GET"

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I have a flow in IBM Integration Bus (IIB) which has a HTTP Input as it's entry node.  I am running this flow on a local Integration Node.  When I deploy the BAR file containing this flow and then attempt to initiate the flow by entering the proper URL in a browser I get an "Unsupported Method: GET" response.  The path suffix for the HTTP Input node is "/startTestFlow".  The complete URL entered in the browser is "http://localhost:7800/startTestFlow".  I attempted to post the same URL in Postman and it got the same response.  That tool at least allowed me to examine the response headers.  They were:

```
Allow →POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Connection →close
Content-Length →24
Date →Tue, 26 Sep 2017 20:51:50 GMT
Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

So the response clearly does not list GET as an approved request method.  The question from me is why and where would this limitation be coming from?

Answer (score 1):

The 7800 is Default SOAP Port.

The ***default HTTP*** Input Node ***port*** is ***7080***.

Answer (score 0):

IIB Integration node has two kinds of listeners for Broker-wide listeners - & Embedded listeners.

Broker-wide listeners at Integration Node level read from default port 7080 & by default HTTPInput Nodes use them.

Embedded listeners at Integration Server(EG) level read from default port 7800 & by default SOAPInput Nodes use them.

**In your case if you haven't changed  the above default configuration, then port 7800 you have hit is being used by some SOAPInput Node  which is giving out this error as SOAP 1.1 only accepts HTTP/POST requests.**

HTTPInpt Node supports both POST & GET methods. Below is the extract from help contents.

> This example uses port 7080, which is the default HTTP port for the
>   broker-wide listener. The default port numbers for the embedded
>   integration server listener are 7800 for HTTP and 7843 for HTTPS. You
>   can change these port numbers, and port ranges that are used by the
>   integration server listeners, by using the mqsichangeproperties
>   command. If you are using SOAP nodes and HTTP nodes in message flows
>   on a single broker, you can choose to handle HTTP messages by using
>   either the broker listener or embedded integration server listeners.
>   If a listener in your configuration receives messages that both
>   SOAPInput and HTTPInput nodes might get, you must carefully check the
>   URL specifications in these nodes. If both URL specifications match an
>   incoming message, the wrong type of node might get the message, and
>   processing might fail or produce unexpected results. This situation
>   occurs if you specify identical values for the Path suffix for URL
>   properties of the HTTPInput node and the SOAPInput node. It can also
>   occur if you use wildcards in either or both specifications, and an
>   incoming message matches both properties. If you want to use the
>   broker listener for HTTP and HTTPS traffic, check that the broker
>   properties for the listener ports for HTTP and HTTPS are suitable. The
>   default port for HTTP is 7080; the default port for HTTPS is 7083. If
>   you want to use the integration server listener, you must configure
>   the integration server by using the mqsichangeproperties command to
>   activate the listener for HTTP and HTTPS messages. The default port
>   for HTTP is 7800; the default port for HTTPS is 7843. You can change
>   these port numbers, and the ranges from which the ports are allocated,
>   by using the mqsichangeproperties command.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc43700_.htm